# How to transfer emails from Win XP to Vista or Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, email, import, outlook-express, windows-vista

I was using Windows XP computer for a long time, and Outlook Express as my email client. I have lots and lots of email I would like to keep and therefore I want to transfer them to my new computer with Windows 7. I have transferred all my settings using Transfer Files and Settings Wizard, however in Win 7 there is a new mail client called Windows Mail, and I cannot see any option in it to import the Outlook Express mails.

How can I transfer my emails from WinXP computer to a Vista or Win7 OS?

Comment: Please see the following post: http://superuser.com/questions/147387/converting-outlook-express-csv-adress-book-and-dbx-files-into-thunderbird-on-w7/209838#209838

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the easiest way how to transfer mails from Outlook Express to Vista/Win7 is to use Mozilla Thunderbird. There is one gotcha to watch for - as the Thunderbird needs to import the mails [from existing installation](https://superuser.com/questions/147387/converting-outlook-express-csv-adress-book-and-dbx-files-into-thunderbird-on-w7) and there is no Outlook Express on Vista/Win 7, one needs to install the Thunderbird on the XP computer and perform the mail import before transferring the profile to a new computer or before installing the OS upgrade.

If you no longer have an access to the XP computer and you only have your identity archived, follow steps in [Converting Outlook Express csv adress book and dbx files into Thunderbird on W7](https://superuser.com/questions/147387/converting-outlook-express-csv-adress-book-and-dbx-files-into-thunderbird-on-w7/209838#209838).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the IMAP protocol (gmail/yahoo/hotmail + dozens of others do this already), you don't need to. (You can check your settings)

Not sure if you are? Download the [Thunderbird](https://www.thunderbird.net/) app, choose "Existing Email Account", and sign into your old account. If you're on IMAP all your old emails will show up automatically. If not, you're probably on POP3, which is the old version that wasn't always synchronized with the cloud.